# How to handle emoji in java and save into database, Then display on UI

Tags: java, html, emoji

I am sending a request on third party api. and a getting response like **âŒš Test** which is actually looks like ⌚ **Test** on third party UI. My question is. In which format  emoji's i should save into database , and how i can display the same emoji on UI as well.

please help

Answer (score 0):

For this you will need to find the correct encoding to store your string in your database.
Since I don't know which DB you're using, you can go trough this tutorial to understand how to define your column in DB to store the correct format. [EXAMPLE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96529/ch5.htm)

Comment: Hello @Razvan  thanks for your quick reply, Do you have any example , How to handle emoji (âŒš Test)  in java code. would really appreciate if you can share

Comment: I haven't worked with this, but read and this is how you can handle it in database. From there, java will take it as a string with special characters and send it after, so you don't need to stress with this part. If you want to avoid storing that data in DB, you can use properties files.